# Deprecation of org.eclipse.ui.actionSets

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

As per [JavaDoc](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_actionSets.html). So does it mean that developers need to switch to new extension point or risk their software not working in the future? When will deprecation happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A large amount of core Eclipse code still makes extensive use of action sets so although it is deprecated it is unlikely that this extension point will ever be removed.

Nevertheless you should plan to use the `org.eclipse.ui.menus`, `org.eclipse.ui.commands`, `org.eclipse.ui.bindings` and `org.eclipse.ui.handlers` instead whenever possible.